# Keeping geting a zero in the main function

Tags: c, function

I added a few printf stantments to see if the information is being computer and passed correctly, and while is is being computed correctly in the calcMean function, I keep getting zeros in the main function. I am not sure where my mistake is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void calcMean(int [], int, float);
void calcVariance(int [], int, float);



int main(void)
{
/*create array and initialize it with values*/
int mainArr [ ] = {71,1899,272,1694,1697,296,722,12,2726,1899,
                ....... 
                    1652,488,1123,17,290,1324,2495,1221,2361,1244,
                    813,2716,1808,2328,2840,1059,2382,2391,2453,1672,
                    1469,778,2639,357,2691,1113,2131,23,2535,1514,
                    2317,45,1465,1799,2642,557,1846,1824,1144,1468,-1};
/*create initilized values for variables*/
float mean = 0.0;
int counter = 0;

calcMean(mainArr, counter, mean);

calcVariance(mainArr, counter, mean);

printf ("Mean: %10.2f\n", mean);       /*gives the average number to one decimal place*/
printf ("counter: %10.0d\n", counter);
getchar();
}/*End of the program*/

void calcMean(int mainArr[], int counter, float mean)/*This function finds the     Mean(average) of the function, and the size of the array*/
{   
int sentinel = -1;
float sum = 0.0;
int index = 0;
for (index; mainArr[index] != sentinel; index++) /*gets the total numbers in the function and the sum*/
{
    counter++;
    sum = sum + mainArr[index];
}       /*end of the sumation and counting of integers*/

printf ("%0.0d\n", counter);
mean = ((float) sum / counter);             /*Divides the sum by the total number of numbers to find the mean*/
printf ("mean: %10.2f\n", mean);
}

void calcVariance(int mainArr[], int counter, float mean)
{
int varindex = 0;
int numerator =0;
int square = 0;
int variance = 0;
int sumation = 0;
for(varindex; varindex<counter; varindex++)
{
    numerator = (mainArr[varindex] - mean);
    square = (numerator * numerator);
    sumation = sumation + square;
    variance = sumation / (counter-1);
}
printf ("variance %10.2f\n", variance);
}
```

Comment: +1 for a nice _complete_ posted question.

Comment: Most of the solutions use pointers, which I am largely unfamiliar with. If someone could give a descriptor on what is going on that would be great. Otherwise, all I am getting confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP later requested an answer with little use of pointers.

As others (@suspectus, @Karoly Horvath, @Carl Norum) correctly *pointed* out the problem that passing into a function `mean` does not change it.

`main()` has an object named `mean`.  That object's value was used to initialize the object called `mean` in the argument list of `calcMean()`.  `calcMean()` proceeded to set its `mean` to some value.  At the end of the function, the original `mean` in `main()` is *not* affected.

Instead, use the *return* value of function `calcMean()` to set `mean` in `main()`.

```
// void calcMean(int mainArr[], int counter, float mean)
float calcMean(int mainArr[], int counter) {
  float mean; 
  ...
  mean = ((float) sum / counter);
  return mean;
}

int main(void) {
  ... 
  float mean = 0.0;
  ...
  // calcMean(mainArr, counter, mean);
  mean = calcMean(mainArr, counter);
  ...
}
```

Do the same for `calcVariance`

Comment: Sorry for the grouping of comments, I had a typo in my code. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming your function changes the value of outer variables. It won't.

```
calcMean(mainArr, counter, mean);
                  ^        ^ pass by value

void calcMean(int mainArr[], int counter, float mean)
                                 ^              ^ receive by value
```

Modifying `counter` inside the function changes only the local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters are ***copied*** into functions. So the variables inside a function will not change the parameters in the outer function.

You will need to do something like the following to any function which you wish to pass back more than one value from a function. (If you only need to pass back one value that can be returned with the function return statement).

// declare the parameters you wish to pass back to calling function as pointers

```
void calcMean(int [], *int, *float);
```

// pass the address of the variables:

```
calcMean(mainArr, &counter, &mean);
```

// obtain the values of the pointers in your calcMean using derefence operator *

```
printf ("%0.0d\n", *counter);
*mean = ((float) sum / *counter);
```

Comment: I tried to use something similar to the first, but I am not sure it is possible to use a pointer in the prototype. I have tried the others but I keep having the program crash. Is is possible for you to elaborate. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

C is a pass-by-value language.  Modifying `mean` and `counter` in the other functions doesn't affect their values in `main()`.